# how to make data table heading dynamic in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, datatable

```
  function list_datatable()
 {

    //function to initialize data table library
    $this->datatable_initialize();
    //set template for table        
    $tmpl = array ('table_open'  => '<table id="list_details"  class="table table-bordered responsive my_table table-striped">' );
    $this->table->set_template($tmpl); 
    //set  th heading for table     
    $this->table->set_heading('ID','Name','DOB','Email','Mobile','Address','Role'); 
    $this->table->set_caption('<colgroup> <col class="con0"> <col class="con1"><col class="con0"> <col class="con1">  <col class="con0"><col class="con1"><col class="con0"> </colgroup>');
}
```

I want to set the data table heading dynamically using database query please help me to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing individual parameters, `set_heading` does accept array. So you can change your code to

```
$this->table->set_heading("", $headingColumns);
```

`$headingColumns` is an array that contains all the column names, that you can fetch from database.

You can find more info here: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/table.html